# Is recommended APACHE OPTIMIZATION: KEEPALIVE ON

Tags: magento-1.9

When I try to export all products, it does not get exported. Is it recommended:

APACHE OPTIMIZATION: KEEPALIVE ON

Comment: in those 20000 products, how many attribute set you created in backend

Comment: 30 attributes are there

Comment: i wanted to know about `ATTRibute SET` if you have many attribute sets, if you go for `system>import/export>Dataflow profiles` click on `export all products` than you can see `Export filters` ,

under that you can see `Attribute set name` , select attribute set and than save profile and run profile. if you have sinlge attribute set than it will not work

Comment: but some products i have not set attributes set,  what about my remaininig products export.

Comment: now the option you can see is `Any attribute set` right ? in the dropdown how many options are there ?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/4BLk6Wt.png

Comment: Audio & video, book, food- you have these 3 attributes sets right ? now select audio video and save and run profile, do same for for all 3 attribute sets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42820/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-baby-in-magento).

Comment: but some product i have dont set attributes set, then what about that product

Answer (score 2):

Keepalive can be good if loading the site causes *many requests* (images, scripts etc).

It has no effect on exporting products, which is *one request*.

Comment: what are all possibilities of restriction for  bulk export products,